# WebView to be exact to the screen size in android app

Tags: android, webview

in my app i am trying to load a webpage. The webpage contains an image. I want the image to be exactly within the android device screen size. I want the image to be fitted to the evice.

In the web contents we have added the view port tag. I have loaded the URL in default browser of the device,the web page looked to be fitted in 2.1 but in 2.2 version the image seems to be very large. So i loaded the URL in a web view as follows

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);         
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(30);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxxx/get_ban/3");
```

Now the image is looking good in 2.2 version and in 2.1 it looks very small.

I want the image to be fitted to the screen size common for all the os version, how to do this......

Comment: Can you edit the HTML of the page? Just set the graphics to 100% width and maybe do some other checking/resizing with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this

```
setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Is it the effect?

Try to use it with

```
setUseWideViewPort(true);
```